# In mkdocs, can I make generated markdown with headers be indexed?

Tags: python, jinja2, mkdocs

I am doing a small site locally using mkdocs. The content is technical documentation, with several repeating and identical sections (not in a table).

To give me flexibility I have put the repetitive information in an sqlite database, and at site generation time, I call a python function to get data from sqlite and return formatted markdown for each element, in a list.

My mkdocs document would be something like

```
## a normal header
some text
<!-- here is the repetitive section -->
{% set thelist=myPythonFunction('some_parameter') %}
{% for i in thelist %}
{{i | safe}}
{% endfor %}
```

This all works. In simplistic example, the generated markdown is

```
## a normal header
some text
<!-- here is the repetitive section -->

## Element1    <!-- not included in TOC -->
*test1*

## Element2    <!-- not included in TOC -->
*test2*
```

But in the generated markdown is a header for every section. These headers do not appear in the mkdocs headers when the page is generated. So it seems to me that the order of header indexing is before the python is called - I would like to have it after.

Is there a setting somewhere to change the order ? Or in some other way make the headers.
If need be, I can return a list of lists from Python, and use macros in the jinja2 template. (not tested, so I do not know if it changes things).

Comment: You render it in runtime and probably it is real-time interpreted. You can render it as raw text, after that send this to rendering?

Comment: Yes, I could absolutely compile the markdown externally, which would trigger a rendering as if I typed the entire thing. I prefer not to if possible, as it's much clearner to have just a few lines to make a dynamic section. It this is not possible, I may go down that route.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mkdocs-macros? This is an interesting question.

I suggest that you open an issue on g[ithub's repository for mkdocs-macros](https://github.com/fralau/mkdocs_macros_plugin/issues), and indicate which versions of mkdocs and mkdocs-macros you are using.